# Mouse and keyboard not working when i resume after suspend ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, suspend

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell inspiron 5537 by USB. Everything worked fine, but after i resume my computer from suspend my touch-pad and my keyboard are not responding. So, i tried to reinstall all input driver but it did not work. It seems like my computer not responde..

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you tried restarting

Comment: yeh.i must try hard reset to continue work

Comment: it might be that you only need to restart a specific service.

Comment: try this methods:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/308188/keyboard-doesnt-respond-after-suspend
http://askubuntu.com/questions/503662/14-04-keyboard-does-not-work-in-login-screen-after-sleep