# Keyboard not working at login screen Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3.9.90. After a standard program update two weeks ago my keyboard stopped working only in the login screen. As a workaround I log in using the screen keyboard. When I'm logged in everything works fine. 
I've tried to boot in recovery mode  and with older kernel, but it's the the same result.

Any suggestions how to fix/debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try working through these solutions? They are for problems after coming back from suspend, but maybe a start.

[14.04 - Keyboard does not work in login screen after sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503662/14-04-keyboard-does-not-work-in-login-screen-after-sleep)

[Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I had gone through those before. But reading them once again made me try to reconfigure the gdm. I changed to lightgdm by doing a "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm". This solved the problem. The problem seems however to be in the gdm. Using Lightgdm now!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for 16.04.

Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`

edit `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to have the value `atkdb.reset i8042.nomux quiet splash` and then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Here's the answer that helped me - https://askubuntu.com/a/817999/623268